# Enabling cross-app Firebase authentication with shared iOS Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, keychain

My problem sounds quite simple: I have an App and also a Share Extension. What I would like to do is to check inside the Share Extension wether or not a user is logged in. For that I found this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on).

Right now, if the user signs in I migrate the signed-in user to a shared keychain (inside the main app):

```
   Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        
        if let userId = result?.user.uid { // successfully signed in
            
            let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
            do {
              try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("teamID.com.example-app.group")
            } catch let error as NSError {
              print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
            }
            Auth.auth().updateCurrentUser(user!) { error in
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not giving me any errors so I guess it is working. But I am facing two major issues at the moment:

**1. Problem inside the main app:**

Like I said the code above works perfeclty fine, I am also loading some data which works fine the first the the user signs up. However if I restart the app, the user doesn't have to sign in again and should be directed to the main view where I retrieve data again for the `currentUser`. But that is failing because `currentUser` is `nil`...

```
static func getWishlists(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ dataArray: Any?, _ dropDownArray: Any?) -> Void) {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid // <- throws error
    ...
```

That function is also called right after the user is signing in (1st code snippet at the top) and is working fine but only the first time.

This is the `error` I get from Firebase:

> 6.21.0 - [Firebase/Auth][I-AUT000001] Error loading saved user when starting up: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17995 "An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_KEYCHAIN_ERROR, NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemCopyMatching (0), NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered}

**2nd problem inside my `Share Extension`:**

Like I said, I would like to check if a user is logged in or not. For that I tried this inside the `Share Extension`:

```
    do {
      try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("teamID.com.example-app.group")
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
    }
    
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      // User is signed in.
      print("signed in")
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
      print("not signed in")
    }
```

But that is printing `not signed in` even though a user just signed in inside the main app.

I have no idea what exactly I am doing wrong here and couldnt find anything in the documentation. Maybe its how I retrieve the data for the user. Maybe I need to call something with `accessGroup` there as well, but I am stuck... Grateful for any help!

Comment: Just confirming, you have the Keychain Sharing capability, right?

Comment: @Pastre yes, on both app and extension with the Same identifier

Comment: What does the `NSError.userInfo` dictionary's `NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey` say?

Comment: @TarunTyagi  I dont know how to read that error...

Comment: Sorry, it's visible in the error log - this part `NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemCopyMatching (0)`. This seems to be an environment/config issue. See this thread - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3215 EXACTLY the same error.

Comment: @TarunTyagi youre Right, same error. I will check the log and Update you. On the Git link they said to clean the entitlement file or something ? How would I do that

Comment: You can use different entitlements for your debug/production build, make sure you use the appropriate one for your environment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc5II.png

Comment: @PeterFriese  For my `ShareExtension` in `Code SIgning Identity` it says ìOS Developer`

Comment: @PeterFriese is this a problem? do I have to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure of your issue but weren't you supposed to change an set your own userAccessToken

```
do {
      try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
    }
    
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      // User is signed in.
      print("signed in")
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
      print("not signed in")
    }
```

Replace your apps userAccessGroup in the place I have put the XXXXXXXXXXXXX placeholder.